# Ruby on Rails: how do I make an http password protected sub domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

I want a subdomain like... admin.example.com

but I want it to require a user and password. Like... the kind that uses teh browser's interface, rather than a database backed authentication system.

what are some good methods of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple:

```
# products_controller.rb
before_filter :authenticate

protected

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    username == "foo" && password == "bar"
  end
end
```

See: http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication

Comment: that covers the authentication part =\ thanks! just need the subdomain now. =\

Answer (score 1):

Write a small rack application.  Both checking if its the correct subdomain and enforcing basic auth can be done easily.

Comment: And in the spirit of railscasts, this one http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3 will tell you everything you wanted to know about subdomains.

Comment: Ah, this is for rails 3. I'm holding off on rails 3 until its out of beta and more webhosts support it.

Comment: It is out of beta and heroku will host it for free.

Comment: well... thats awesome then. =)